# Prevent Website from Jumping on Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website here: https://lfc2015.ca/ What happens is that the page will display, then jump when the main image/js are loaded. I have tried a preloader, but I really don't like how it slows down the whole site. I have also tried preloading just the image by having it display a solid colour at first (like this http://www.mayneislandcamping.com/), however, the same issue persists. Even solid colours jump like that. I'm thinking if there's a way to tell the browser the height of the div to prevent the jumping? Or I'm open to other answers. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could tell, the issue is that the element isn't being sized till after the script fires. This is because it's height is determined by the script and not by CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing my thought on this,

You can a create a div that overlaps your whole website

```
  .overlay
  {
       position:fixed;
       width:100%;
       height:100%;
       overflow-x:hidden;
       overflow-y:hidden;
       z-index:1000;
  }

  <div class="overlay"><!-- DISPLAY A ANIMATED GIF OR LOADING TEXT--></div>
```

This div will be the first thing that will be loaded in your page.

After some time later using setTimeout() hide the div in graceful manner [fadeout slide animations] have a cool post preload effect.

Hope it helps!